# Is there any way to disable the rank order in rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I have nodes abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4

Input = abcd1,abcd3,abcd4,abcd2

If the rank order ascending - execution follows- abcd1,abcd2,abcd3,abcd4  order
IF the rank order descending - execution follows -abcd4,abcd3,abcd2,abcd1 order
.
I want my executions to follow same order as input i.e, abcd1,abcd3,abcd4,abcd2 . How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Rank Attribute" option on your job definition, for that, just define (or use) some attribute on your node source and Rundeck use it, for example, using this `resources.xml` (check `myorder` custom attribute):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="" myorder="02" hostname="192.168.33.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
  <node name="node01" description="Node 01" tags="" myorder="03" hostname="192.168.33.21" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
  <node name="node02" description="Node 02" tags="" myorder="01" hostname="192.168.33.22" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
</project>
```

Now [set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9AXB.jpg) set "Rank Attribute" textbox with `myorder` attribute, save the job and run again. You can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1igA.jpg) the order based on that attribute.

More information [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/job-v20.html#rankattribute).

#### UPDATE 30/07/2020:

Following the first comment of this answer, exist a way to modify the resource.xml file with a bash script, later update the node definition and later launch the child job to new rankAttribute order using [Job Reference Step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step).

First, the script that changes the Rundeck Model Source (needs [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

path=$RD_OPTION_PATH
myorder=$RD_OPTION_NODE_ORDER
counter=1
Field_Separator=$IFS
 
# set comma as internal field separator for the string list
IFS=,
for value in $myorder;
do
    echo $counter
    xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/project/node[$counter][@myorder]/@myorder" -v $value $path
    counter=$((counter+1))
done
 
IFS=$Field_Separator
```

Now, the Parent Job (that calls the script above, refresh the Rundeck Model Source and finally launch the "target" job):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='node_order' value='3,2,1' />
        <option name='path' required='true' value='/home/m68k/Rundeck/resources/farm.xml' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>860e7189-f399-47c4-ab86-5b47017188dd</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Parent</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>true</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='sequential'>
      <command>
        <description>Just a message</description>
        <exec>echo "Starting..."</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>Call the script</description>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptfile>/home/m68k/Downloads/TEST.sh</scriptfile>
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>Refresh Rundeck Model Source</description>
        <step-plugin type='source-refresh-plugin'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='sleep' value='5' />
          </configuration>
        </step-plugin>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>And launch the "target" job against the new node order</description>
        <jobref name='Child' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>0e02890e-c9dd-4a65-ace1-bfe90b9b7a8e</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>860e7189-f399-47c4-ab86-5b47017188dd</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

And finally, the Child Job, the "target job".

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankAttribute>myorder</rankAttribute>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>0e02890e-c9dd-4a65-ace1-bfe90b9b7a8e</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Child</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "Hello ${node.name}"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>0e02890e-c9dd-4a65-ace1-bfe90b9b7a8e</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

So, if you set `3,1,2` order, you can see the result on `myorder` attribute on `resources.xml` file and the child job executes on that order.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="" hostname="192.168.33.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" myorder="3"/>
  <node name="node01" description="Node 01" tags="" hostname="192.168.33.21" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" myorder="1"/>
  <node name="node02" description="Node 02" tags="" hostname="192.168.33.22" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck" myorder="2"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply . For every use case, the node order will change, and hence hardcoding during the bootstrapping might not help.

Comment: I see!, I updated the answer with a way to do that using Job Reference Step, hope it helps!