# Rundeck Manual Node Order

Tags: rundeck

I am using Rundeck to handle some server reboot operations to apply updates when needed and to refresh some servers that need to be rebooted on a regular basis. I am using Ansible on the backend to handle the inventory via a dynamic inventory plugin (Ansible queries Netbox for this). The function of this seems to be going smoothly aside from the fact that I cannot seem to figure out how to specify a manual node order for the nodes inside of a single job. I know that the Rank Attribute is supposed to be a means to accomplish this, but the documentation of how to use this and any examples doesn't really seem to exists.

Can I get more details on how I can go about specifying a manual order to the hosts within a job? As a stop-gap in the meantime, I have created one job per node and I only set one of the jobs to have a schedule and the other jobs get called one at a time in sequential order as a workflow step to accomplish me being able to control the node order, but this seems absurd to have to handle it this way via separate jobs. If I can make this work with the Rank Attribute feature or some other means, and in light of a dynamic inventory built from Netbox / Ansible, that would help me better simplify this and not have to create a job per node to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use the "Rank Attribute" option in your job definition, you need to define an attributte in your node sources and pass it to the Rank Attribute textbox, for example, using this `resources.xml` (check `myorder` custom attribute):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="" myorder="02" hostname="192.168.33.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
  <node name="node01" description="Node 01" tags="" myorder="03" hostname="192.168.33.21" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
  <node name="node02" description="Node 02" tags="" myorder="01" hostname="192.168.33.22" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
</project>
```

Then [set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9AXB.jpg) "Rank Attribute" textbox with the `myorder` attribute, save the job and run again. You can see your job running in the order based on that attribute (or any other).

So, Rundeck needs the nodes at Model Source to achieve this, a good idea is to use the [ansible model source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011639/rundeck-integration-with-ansible-through-plugin) to get the nodes at the Rundeck "nodes" section and use any attribute or just create a special one using Node Enhancer, take look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-enhancers.html#attribute-match).

More information [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/job-v20.html#rankattribute).

Based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137864/10426011) answer (check the update, probably it helps you).

Comment: I'll investigate Node Enhancers as a possible solution as manually setting something in a a resource file would entirely negate the purpose of having a dynamic inventory built by ansible, so the first mentioned option I don't really see fitting into my current setup.

Comment: This appears to mostly be working. I was able to make it work with an attribute of something like "hostname==xxxxxxxx" to match the FQDN and then add an attribute. I cannot seem to find out how to do this with a tag, though. "tags==xxxxxxxx" using an existing tag on the node will not come back as a match for some reason.