# Can we read xml file and update tag value using OCP command. I have update to tomcat context.xml from rundeck job

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, rundeck

Can we read xml file and update tag value using OCP command. I have to update tomcat context.xml from rundeck job.

Comment: The easiest way is to use xmlstarlet to read and modify the file in an inline script step: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmlstarlet

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate XML files using the [xmlstarlet](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmlstarlet) tool in your Rundeck workflow, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137864/10426011) answer shows you how to do it in an [inline-script](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) Rundeck step.